# How to change file type in solution explorer from Form to Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I accidentally added some .cs files to project as Form instead of Class. Now in Solution Explorer they keep showing up as Form with Form icon (and opening Designer as default).

How can i change them to class type?

Answer (score 7):

- Unload the project (right click, Unload project)
- Edit the csproj file (right click, Edit YourProject.csproj)
- Locate the `<Compile>` element that refers to your C# file
- Remove the `<SubType>` subelement (or change its content from `Form` to `Code`)
- Reload the project

Comment: Tried that and few secconds after loading project back icons change back to Form.

Comment: Does your class inherit from Form? if it does, you can't do anything about it... however you can change the default editor (right click, open with) if you want the code view by default

Comment: @Diabl0 : Have you tried this answer in conjunction with editing your .cs file to remove the Form inheritance (": Form") before reloading the project?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new class file and copy+paste the code over. Remove the inheritance from Form, too.

If you want to preserve your SVN history try:

1. Open the folder containing the file
2. SVN rename only the .cs to a new name
3. Go to VS, include the renamed file into your project
4. Remove the inheritance from `Form` and all cruft like initialize component in your constructor
5. Delete the old forms file

Comment: It's some solution, but screw my subversion history :( Now it's question - have project in order or put some mess in svn :)

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the `Form class's designer.cs`. Then remove inheritance from `Form` and `InitializeComponets() call.` In ***.csproj file**, find the `form name` and replace respective `<SubType>Form</SubType>` element.