# My unit test project icon is displaying like a class library... how to fix?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have 2 c# test projects in my VS2012 Update 1 solution, one shows a class library icon, one shows a test project icon.  They both work as test project, but the discrepancy is driving me crazy.  (short drive).  Anybody know how to fix this?  I've looked at the .csproj and the .sln files, but nothing is leaping out at me.

Comment: So for clarity do you mean the icons that show up in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: @tmwoods That is correct.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747588/how-to-change-file-type-in-solution-explorer-from-form-to-class)? It looks like this works but screws up SVN history if you are using subversion at all. I'll keep experimenting too, now I'm curious.

Comment: Any luck? I am still curious :)

Comment: Sigh... none.  Oddly enough, now my other test project is coming up as a class library.  At least it's consistent now.

Comment: Fixed in Vs 2019. Just restore packages and icon will be updated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really a solution, but it seems to be a bug in Visual Studio.

See Microsoft Connect issues [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/778622/solution-explorer-displays-incorrect-icons-for-unit-test-projects), [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/764003/visual-studio-2012-displays-wrong-icon-for-test-project) and [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774775) which you can follow.

There is also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528335/visual-studio-2012-displays-wrong-icon-for-test-project).

**UPDATE:**

This seems to be resolved in Visual Studio 2013 preview.

Comment: And is a problem again in vs 2017!

Answer (score 18):

- Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and choose Edit Project File
- Add a new child in the `<PropertyGroup>` node:

  `<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>`
- Save your changes and close the file
- Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and choose Reload Project

https://adamprescott.net/2012/03/29/convert-a-class-library-to-a-test-project-in-visual-studio/

Comment: This is the actual answer for the problem. However, it should also include the several project types as found on https://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx.

Comment: 2021-09 update: up to date project types (for Visual Studio 2019) could be found here: https://github.com/VISTALL/visual-studio-project-type-guids

Answer (score 7):

If your project is on a new-style `.csproj` file (less verbose, says like `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` as the top line, supports globbing etc), then you can get a test tube icon for your project by either adding `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` NuGet package to your project, or adding this line to your `.csproj` file (which amounts to the same thing):

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.6.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

(Version number correct at the time of writing - check for what the latest is.)

Comment: This answer was very helpful for migrating a 'legacy-style' test project to the new SDK style.

Answer (score 5):

Pawel's answer is right, but it was truncated by the html parser... Mentioned child node should look like:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

This line could be also directly added to the csproj file (to the main PropertyGroup).

Answer (score -2):

Open up Solution Explorer, right-click, go to properties and under 'Application' there is a drop-down menu called 'Output Type' and change that from Class Library to whatever you want it (most likely an Application).

Comment: Well, technically a test project *is* a class library; it just usually has a different icon because it's a specialized type of class library.